# How to use ASP.Net membership with my own tables?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-authentication

Usually, for using the ASP.Net membership APIs, I import the API's tables to my database and use it.
But there is a lot of tables and fields that I don't want them. I just want to have my USERS table that have three fields (like; UserId, Username, Password. Just this). 
So how can I connect this API to my own table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to implement your own custom `MembershipProvider`.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom membership provider. There's a video on asp.net that shows you how to do that:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider